# Django + AngularJS: REST-like endpoints without the Django REST framework using plain URLs and views?

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, django-views, django-rest-framework

We are just starting to create a new product. We would like to use Django at the backend and Angular at the frontend to form a single page app. 
This means we would not be using Django's templating system at all (except for maybe the one necessary HTML file, but this one could be static).

Doing research we have come across the Django REST framework which offers REST functionality for Django allowing easy communication from Angular.

Since we are all more or less new to web development we asked a guy who is maintaining python packages. From his experience with the REST framework he suggested us to scrap the idea to use it since it would clutter up the code (serializers), would be slow, introduce other problems etc.

We are now thinking of using plain Django and designing the URL structure as REST-like endpoints for Angular. We would have one view method for each URL, then perform an action depending on the request type (GET, POST, PUT...) and return only JSON.

Is this a good idea? What would we lose in respect to using the REST framework? What would we gain? Will using Angular for server calls be at all different for any of those approaches?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fun of DRF but I've been using it in a couple of projects lately. The answer to most of your questions is application-dependent, that meaning size and type of your webapp matter.

For what I took away from using DRF it could give you a boost on:

- **Objects serialization** (and validation): I think it's much easier (avoids typing) making the serializers thru' DRF instead of building them in Django. While models and querysets and usually easy done, if you need some more structured JSON response the DRF layer to support the serialization helps.
- **Permissions and authentication**: being addressed to REST APIs there are good shourtcuts to provide security and restrict access to methods, both in terms of methods type and user permissions checking.
- **Plugins**: if you have to deal (you'll probably do) with CORS and/or token-based authorization there are a bunch of niceties you can plug into DRF to get the work done. I am not sure it is that straightforward to put them in place direcly in Django.

That said the **CONS**:

- If you start by using the high-level interfaces of DRF (Viewsets, Routers and the like) you'll eventually end-up refactoring a little bit to address specific needs for which you'll need more control over the code.
- As Django is already a quite big ecosystem, DRJ adds'up to the steepness of the learning curve, probably slowing down a little the implementation, at first.
- Don't know about the performances of the requests passing thru' DRF, but I wouldn't care that much unless your app has specific requirements. DRF wan't probably add up much on well-written code (...and queries to the DB).

These were my two cents. Hope it helps.